# Bisection method to find root of sin(x) in c recursively

Tags: c

I want to find the root of `sin(x)` function by approximating an interval [a,b] recursively, but my output is:

```
-0.350783
```

But I want to get

```
3.1415
```

This is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double dicho(double a,double b)
{
    double m=(a+b)/2;
    double eps=0.000001;

    if((b-a)>=eps)
    {
        if(abs(sin(0)-sin(m))<=eps){
            return m;
        }

        if(sin(m)<0){
            a=m;
        }

        if(sin(m)>0){
            b=m;    
        }
        dicho(a,b);
    }
}

void main()
{
    int a,b;
    a=3;
    b=4;
    double res=sin(dicho(a,b));
    printf("%lf\n",res);
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Clean up all your warnings! You need to add return statements.

Comment: But i didnt get any warnings, just a wrong result.

Comment: Then you need to increase warning level. For gcc at least do `gcc -Wall file.c`

Comment: What is the purpose of `sin(0)` ?

Comment: because the root of sin(x) is x=0

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) then compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Since you are doing floating point math, be sure to read https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @Ayano `sin(0)` is zero - so there is no need for that code

Comment: @Ayano BTW: See updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything [klutt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699433/klutt) said. But there's also a glitch in your algorithm. Namely in the `[3, 4]`  interval the sine function is strictly decreasing and this breaks down your logic a little bit.

Reworking your `dicho` function something like this seems to work:

```
double dicho(double a,double b)
{
    double m=(a+b)/2;
    double eps=0.000001;

    if((b-a)>=eps)
    {
        printf("a: %lf b: %lf, m: %lf diff: %lf\n",
            a, b, m, sin(0) - sin(m));

        if(fabs(sin(0)-sin(m)) <= eps){
            return m;
        }

        if(sin(m) < 0){
            b = m; // look in [a, (a+b)/2]
        }

        if(sin(m)>0){
            a = m; // look in [[a+b]/2, b]
        }

        return dicho(a,b);
    }

    return m;
}
```

When running with this function you can see the solution actually converges towards pi:

```
a: 3.000000 b: 4.000000, m: 3.500000 diff: 0.350783
a: 3.000000 b: 3.500000, m: 3.250000 diff: 0.108195
a: 3.000000 b: 3.250000, m: 3.125000 diff: -0.016592
a: 3.125000 b: 3.250000, m: 3.187500 diff: 0.045891
a: 3.125000 b: 3.187500, m: 3.156250 diff: 0.014657
a: 3.125000 b: 3.156250, m: 3.140625 diff: -0.000968
a: 3.140625 b: 3.156250, m: 3.148438 diff: 0.006845
a: 3.140625 b: 3.148438, m: 3.144531 diff: 0.002939
a: 3.140625 b: 3.144531, m: 3.142578 diff: 0.000985
a: 3.140625 b: 3.142578, m: 3.141602 diff: 0.000009
a: 3.140625 b: 3.141602, m: 3.141113 diff: -0.000479
a: 3.141113 b: 3.141602, m: 3.141357 diff: -0.000235
a: 3.141357 b: 3.141602, m: 3.141479 diff: -0.000113
a: 3.141479 b: 3.141602, m: 3.141541 diff: -0.000052
a: 3.141541 b: 3.141602, m: 3.141571 diff: -0.000022
a: 3.141571 b: 3.141602, m: 3.141586 diff: -0.000006
a: 3.141586 b: 3.141602, m: 3.141594 diff: 0.000001
a: 3.141586 b: 3.141594, m: 3.141590 diff: -0.000003
a: 3.141590 b: 3.141594, m: 3.141592 diff: -0.000001
3.141592
```

But with your original recursion logic (use `fabs` instead of `abs` though):

```
a: 3.000000 b: 4.000000, m: 3.500000 diff: 0.350783
a: 3.500000 b: 4.000000, m: 3.750000 diff: 0.571561
a: 3.750000 b: 4.000000, m: 3.875000 diff: 0.669405
a: 3.875000 b: 4.000000, m: 3.937500 diff: 0.714499
a: 3.937500 b: 4.000000, m: 3.968750 diff: 0.736010
a: 3.968750 b: 4.000000, m: 3.984375 diff: 0.746497
a: 3.984375 b: 4.000000, m: 3.992188 diff: 0.751673
a: 3.992188 b: 4.000000, m: 3.996094 diff: 0.754243
a: 3.996094 b: 4.000000, m: 3.998047 diff: 0.755524
a: 3.998047 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999023 diff: 0.756164
a: 3.999023 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999512 diff: 0.756483
a: 3.999512 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999756 diff: 0.756643
a: 3.999756 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999878 diff: 0.756723
a: 3.999878 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999939 diff: 0.756763
a: 3.999939 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999969 diff: 0.756783
a: 3.999969 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999985 diff: 0.756793
a: 3.999985 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999992 diff: 0.756798
a: 3.999992 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999996 diff: 0.756800
a: 3.999996 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999998 diff: 0.756801
a: 3.999998 b: 4.000000, m: 3.999999 diff: 0.756802
4.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

When compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` this code gives me three warnings.

```
$ gcc b.c -lm -Wall -Wextra
b.c: In function ‘dicho’:
b.c:12:12: warning: using integer absolute value function ‘abs’ when argument is of floating point type ‘double’ [-Wabsolute-value]
   12 |         if(abs(sin(0)-sin(m))<=eps){
      |            ^~~
b.c: At top level:
b.c:28:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
   28 | void main()
      |      ^~~~
b.c: In function ‘dicho’:
b.c:26:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   26 | }
      | ^
```

You need to:

- Change the signature of main to `int main()`
- Change `abs` to `fabs`
- Make sure that the recursive function actually does return. For instance, the recursive call `dicho(a,b);` within the `dicho` function should be `return dicho(a,b);` Also, what happens if `(b-a)<eps`? You should return something there too.
- What happens if `sin(m)` evaluates to 0? Then you would be stuck in an endless loop. Well, not really because `fabs(sin(0)-sin(m))<=eps` will catch that case, but were you really aware of that? ;)

This does not solve the issue with wrong output, but it is the minimum on your way to solving it.

Answer (score 3):

You have some serious programming errors like using integer `abs` where you should use floating point `fabs` and missing return statements.

But the worst part is the algorithm is wrong. When the algorithm is wrong, it won't help to fix the programming errors. The program will still fail.

The main problem with your algorithm is that you assume that `sin(a)` is less than zero and that `sin(b)` is greater than zero. You can't just assume that!

You need to handle all cases - for instance:

```
if (sin(a) > 0 && sin(b) > 0)
{
    // both greater than zero

    // What to do now ??? Maybe there isn't a solution in this interval
}

if (sin(a) < 0 && sin(b) < 0)
{
    // both less than zero

    // What to do now ??? Maybe there isn't a solution in this interval
}

if (sin(a) > 0)
{
    // sin(a) larger than sin(b)

    // Do recursive call
    return dicho(?, ?);
}
else
{
    // sin(a) less than sin(b)

    // Do recursive call
    return dicho(?, ?);
}
```

But what to put into the recursive call ?

Your approach is to do

```
return dicho(a, (a+b)/2));
```

in one case and

```
return dicho((a+b)/2), b);
```

in the other.

But that will not work!

Assume the following:

- `sin(a)` is less than zero
- `sin(b)` is greater than zero
- `sin((a+b)/2)` is **greater** than zero

In this case we can do:

```
option 1:

return dicho((a+b)/2), b); // very bad as both are now greater than zero

option 2:

return dicho(a, (a+b)/2)); // good! one negative and one positive
```

So from this you see that just cutting the interval in half isn't a good idea. You need to add code that checks whether `sin` at the middle point is less or greater than zero and then do the call for the correct sub-interval (depending on the value of `sin(a)` and `sin(b)`)

Something like:

```
if (sin(a) > 0)
{
    // sin(a) larger than sin(b)

    if (sin((a+b)/2) > 0)
    {
        return dicho((a+b)/2, b);
    }
    return dicho(a, (a+b)/2);
}
else
{
    // sin(a) less than sin(b)

    .... similar to the aboove code    
}
```

Putting all cases into a truth table is often very helpful. Like:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fabs(sin(a)) < eps |             |                  | return a;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fabs(sin(b)) < eps |             |                  | return b;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sin(a) > 0         |  sin(b) > 0 |                  | oh dear - bad
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sin(a) < 0         |  sin(b) < 0 |                  | oh dear - bad
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sin(a) > 0         |  sin(b) < 0 | sin((a+b)/2) > 0 | return dicho((a+b)/2), b);
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sin(a) > 0         |  sin(b) < 0 | sin((a+b)/2) < 0 | return dicho(a, (a+b)/2));
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sin(a) < 0         |  sin(b) > 0 | sin((a+b)/2) > 0 | return dicho(a, (a+b)/2));
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sin(a) < 0         |  sin(b) > 0 | sin((a+b)/2) < 0 | return dicho((a+b)/2), b);
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

clang is even more helpful, suggesting that you use `fabs`

```
so6.c:12:12: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
        if(abs(sin(0)-sin(m))<=eps){
           ^
so6.c:12:12: note: use function 'fabs' instead
        if(abs(sin(0)-sin(m))<=eps){
           ^~~
           fabs
so6.c:25:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```